# Javascript Cannot send message to pop up window with window.postMessage

Tags: javascript, html

The event in the pop up window **DOES** trigger but the actual data is always :

> {'messageId' : 0, 'value': false}

In my parent window:

```
  $('.myChatButton').click(function () {

       let params = 'resizable=no,width=1200,height=800';

       var chatWindow = window.open('http://localhost/Support/Chat-Server', 'windowName', params);

       try {
             chatWindow.postMessage('testMessage', "http://localhost/Support/Chat-Server");
        }
        catch (e) {
             console.log(e.message);
        }

   });
```

In my pop up window:

// the window ready function:

```
   $(function () {
      // added once true because for some reason this event was fired 3 times when clicked to open pop-up
      window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, { once: true}); 
   });

    function receiveMessage(event) {        
        console.log(event.data);
    }
```

Comment: That `event.data` is coming from a different `postMessage()` call.

Comment: @Barmar which different postMessage() call..and how can I send data from the window where I call window.open(...) to the target pop up please?

Comment: It's somewhere in the code you haven't posted. Your code sends a string, but the listener is receiving an object. Search all your code for something with `messageId`

Comment: @Barmar Makes sense what you say, but I CTRL-F the index pages on both parent and pop up and never found a "messageId" variable. I do have a messaging system set up with SignalR and a web api for db crud operations but that specific variable name does not exist. I was also wondering where that is coming from....

Comment: What's in `event.origin`?

Comment: @Barmar about that, qood question. Its "https://vars.hotjar.com" which is totally unrelated and dont know what it is..... I am also using DNN if that adds any relevant info

Comment: hotjar.com is a website analytics service. My guess is that it detects when you create a popup window and sends it a message.